# AWAIT multiple file downloads with DownloadDataAsync

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, webclient

I have a zip file creator that takes in a `String[]` of Urls, and returns a zip file with all of the files in the `String[]`

I figured there would be a number of example of this, but I cannot seem to find an answer to "How to download many files asynchronously and return when done"

How do I download {n} files at once, and return the Dictionary only when all downloads are complete?

```
private static Dictionary<string, byte[]> ReturnedFileData(IEnumerable<string> urlList)
{
    var returnList = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        foreach (var url in urlList)
        {
            client.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender1, e1) => returnList.Add(GetFileNameFromUrlString(url), e1.Result);
            client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}

private static string GetFileNameFromUrlString(string url)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- First, you tagged your question with `async-await` without actually using it. There really is no reason anymore to use the old asynchronous paradigms.
- To wait **asynchronously** for all concurrent `async` operation to complete you should use `Task.WhenAll` which means that you need to keep all the tasks in some construct (i.e. dictionary) before actually extracting their results.
- At the end, when you have all the results in hand you just create the new result dictionary by parsing the `uri` into the file name, and extracting the result out of the `async` tasks.

```
async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> ReturnFileData(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var dictionary = urls.ToDictionary(
        url => new Uri(url),
        url => new WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync(url));

    await Task.WhenAll(dictionary.Values);

    return dictionary.ToDictionary(
        pair => Path.GetFileName(pair.Key.LocalPath),
        pair => pair.Value.Result);
}
```

Comment: I marked this correct, but as I incorporate it into the code, I'm getting threading errors. I replaced the `ASYNC` code with this sample and can return the `Byte[]` properly, but I'm not able to cast the object with your pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874477/why-is-the-async-ctp-performing-poorly

Comment: @Wesley That sample creates a new `WebClient` for each request, where you didn't. `WebClient` isn't thread-safe (and evidently doesn't support concurrent async calls).

Comment: Thanks for trying @|3arnon. It seems to be more than the `WebClient` creation, as the method is still trying to return before completing. In the other example, we're creating a task collection and calling `WhenAll` directly on the `Task` Collection before running a LINQ call on the returned results. I might just need to mess around with it for a bit and come back unless you have another approach.

Comment: @Wesley The same thing happens here (only the tasks are in a Dictionary and not an IEnumerable). The method doesn't return before completion because Task.WhenAll waits for all the tasks to end, and if it didn't, Task.Result would have.

Comment: [HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551753(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better choice because HttpClient is thread-safe, you can use a single instance for all calls and you only have one instance to dispose of

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string JUST_return_dataURL_by_URL(string URL, int interval, int max_interval)
    {
        var client = new WebClient(proxy);
        client.Headers = _headers;
        string downloaded_from_URL = "false";       //default - until downloading
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += bytes => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            string dataURL = Convert.ToBase64String( bytes );
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Trim('{', '}')+".png";
            downloaded_from_URL =
                        "Image Downloaded from " + URL
                    +   "<br>"
                    +   "<a href=\""+dataURL+"\" download=\""+filename+"\">"
                    +       "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + dataURL + "\"/>"+filename
                    +   "</a>"
            ;
            return;
        };
        client.DownloadDataAsync(new System.Uri(URL));

        int i = 0;
        do{
        //  Console.WriteLine(
        //      "(interval > 10): "+(interval > 10)
        //      +"\n(downloaded_from_URL == \"false\"): " + (downloaded_from_URL == "false")
        //      +"\ninterval: "+interval
        //  );
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
            i+=interval;
        }
        while( (downloaded_from_URL == "false") && (i < max_interval) );

        return downloaded_from_URL;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd be wanting the task.WaitAll method...

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Create each download as a separate task, then pass them as a collection.

A shortcut to this might be to wrap your download method in a task.

```
Return new Task<downloadresult>(()=>{ method body});
```

Apologies for vagueness, working on iPad sucks for coding.

**EDIT:**

Another implementation of this that may be worth considering is wrapping the downloads using the parallel framework.

Since your tasks all do the same thing taking a parameter, you could instead use Parallel.Foreach and wrap that into a single task:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>> DownloadTask(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> urlList)
        {
            return new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, byte[]>>(() =>
            {
                var r = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte[]>();
                System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<string>(urlList, (url, s, l) =>
                {
                    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
                    {
                        var bytedata = client.DownloadData(url);
                        r.TryAdd(url, bytedata);
                    }
                });


                var results = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
                foreach (var value in r)
                {
                    results.Add(value.Key, value.Value);
                }

                return results;
            });
        }
```

This leverages a concurrent collection to support parallel access within the method before converting back to IDictionary.

This method returns a task so can be called with an await.

Hope this provides a helpful alternative.

Comment: It looks like I need to replace `DownloadDataAsync` with `DownloadDataTaskAsync`. This answer says to me "Go learn the MSFT Async stack and come back when you know more." Can I get an example with more detail?

Comment: @Wesley You're correct; that's not an appropriate answer.  Of course, your question just about reads as, "I can't be bothered to learn how to write an asynchronous program, so you go write it for me so that I don't need to learn how to do it." which is *also* not appropriate.

Comment: The alternative isn't asynchronous and so less scalable.

Comment: It returns a type of Task which can be awaited, making it asynchronous. Internally it then processes the input collection in parallel threads.

Comment: @kidshaw The actual IO operation (`DownloadData`) is synchronous, so you are holding these threads throughout the entire operation. That hurts scalability.

Comment: They form part of the parallel body so each web client gets disposed at the end of the iteration. Each iteration is handled by the parallel library with new threads being spawned as the framework sees fit - it will often feature far less threads than number of elements. Importantly, the threads are managed and disposed within the parallel framework - I don't see anything here that would cause the thread to be held.